# How to update the consumer provider data within a function not a widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to update my data provider from within a function.  I don't know how to update the provider from a function, but I know how to update from a Widget.  I'm wondering if that is possible to update the provider data without a Widget.

If I run the data provider update within Widget after a button click event, then it works fine, however I want to update it from a function.

I try the following code but it doesn't work.

```
void changeData() {

Consumer<MyProvider>(builder: (context, myProvider, child) {
      myProvider.setData(newData);
      
    });
 }
```

Here's my provider:

```
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<MyModel> currentData = [];

  void setData(value) {
    currentData = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provider is correct but to do it you first need to initialise the provider in the main.dart. You can do it like this-

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyProvider(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

And then you can change it with the function

```
void changeData(BuildContext context, List<MyModel> newData) {
  MyProvider myProvider = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false);
  myProvider.setData(newData);
}


changeData(context, newData);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your answer.  It help me with the solution.  I don't have to initialise  in the `runApp`.   I just add the `MultiProvider(provders: [])` in my build Widget then its good enough to run the data change inside my function, like you shows on your answer.  Thanks you mate.